# Starting a TCP server from terminal

Tags: macos, tcp, terminal, netcat

How do I start a TCP server from the terminal on port 13370 using nc? I was following a tutorial that required starting up a TCP server on 13370 and send requests through it. The tut advised me to open the TCP server using "nc" How do I go on achieving this?

Comment: Have you read the manual page for `nc`? Most versions include some pretty clear examples.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From nc documentation:

> It is quite simple to build a very basic client/server model using nc.
> On one console, start nc lis-tening listening on a specific port for a
> connection

You should use -l parameter, for listening on port 13370:

```
$ nc -l 13370
```

Now you have a tcp server on 127.0.0.1:13370

On a second console you could connect to your server by using:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 13370
```

Please refer also to the documentation [link.](https://ss64.com/mac/nc.html)